# Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException in SQL query

Tags: sql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a CosmosDB function that returns two values ​​separated by pipe.
I have to assign these values ​​to the respective fields and then convert them to float.

Already at the separation I get an exception of syntax error with the CHARINDEX function.

```
    sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += "udf.UDF_Wh_Varh(c.Wh,c.Varh) as temp, ";
    sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += " LEFT(temp, CHARINDEX(',', temp) - 1) as Wh, ";  
    sqlQuerySpec.QueryText += " RIGHT(temp, CHARINDEX('|', REVERSE(temp)) - 1) as Varh, ";
```

If I then add the CAST to float it stops me on that.

The problem seems to be related to the recognition of the temp identifier, but I haven't found a way to declare it.. I cannot call the function more than once because I have already reached the 10 function limit.

I wait suggestions.

Thanks in advance,

Simone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `CHARINDEX` nor `CAST` are in the Cosmos DB querying language, that's why  your query is not accepted.

The only acceptable string functions are: CONCAT, CONTAINS, ENDSWITH, INDEX_OF, LEFT, LENGTH, LOWER, LTRIM, REPLACE, REPLICATE, REVERSE, RIGHT, RTRIM, STARTSWITH, SUBSTRING, and UPPER.

You can find a very useful Cosmos DB querying [cheat sheet here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/query-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thank you.  Could you please suggest me an alternative way to write my query using supported query? Thanks in andvance. Simone

Comment: @SimoneSpagna The easiest way to go about it is to write your own UDFs that will do what `CHARINDEX` and `REVERSE` would do. The Cosmos DB SQL itself is quite limited so I don't think you can achieve it without using UDFs.

Comment: The problem is that I have reached the maximum number of udf that can be called (10).

Comment: @SimoneSpagna Ouch. Then I don't know what would be best. Could you merge some UDFs together?